# How to correctly augment Any?

Tags: raku

The following program:

```
use v6.c;

use MONKEY-TYPING;

augment class Any {
    method show0 { self.say }}

augment class List {
    method show1 { self.say }}

<hello world>.show0;
<hello world>.show1;
```

produces the expected output of:

```
(hello world)
(hello world)
```

While this one:

```
use v6.c;

use MONKEY-TYPING;

augment class Any {
    method show0 { self.say }}

<hello world>.show0;
```

produces an error:

```
No such method 'show0' for invocant of type 'List'. Did you mean 'show0'?
  in block <unit> at showcase.p6 line 9
```

Is that a bug or am I just holding it wrong?

Comment: Interestingly the correct method gets actually suggested.

Comment: .oO( the two hardest problems in programming are naming, **cache invalidation** and off-by-one errors... )

Comment: `:hello('world').show0;` will indeed fail in the first example

Comment: you could also try `.Any::show0`

Comment: This is a bug. SO isn't a good place to process it. I think this is the sort of question that would almost certainly be quickly resolved by [asking about it on the #perl6 IRC channel](https://kiwiirc.com/nextclient/irc.freenode.com/#perl6). They'd use evalbots to immediately pin down when this broke (assuming it ever worked), understand why it broke, and fix it, more often than not within a few hours/days.

Comment: I agree, I will open an issue in the rakudo issue tracker.

Comment: For reference: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2356

Comment: Hmm. Well I'd say I'm almost entirely wrong about it being a bug / broken / quickfixable and SO not being the place to discuss it. Liz's answer explains the situation. I should have been less assertive (as always) and paid more attention to the fact a `use MONKEY*` was involved. That said, now we have both an issue, thank you, and an SO Q+A, thanks to you and Liz, recording the details. I'll consider that a blessing. I'll leave my incorrect comment up because it's true when something actually *is* definitely just an ordinary bug.

Comment: There is at least a bit of a bug here and if only the misleading error message.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all: augmenting core classes, at least in the foreseeable future of Rakudo Perl 6, is **not** a good idea.  It doesn't play well with precompilation.

Secondly: when a class is a subclass of another class, the subclass "knows" from which it inherits.  Alas, this doesn't work the other way around: a class does not know of its subclasses (at least at the moment of this writing).

This means that if you augment `Any`, none of its subclasses know that should also re-compose themselves.  In your first example, you do that with the `List` class by augmenting that.  However, if you would reverse the order of the augments, it wouldn't work either, because the `List` class would get re-composed before the `Any` class would get re-composed.

It's therefore that it's recommended to mix any extra methods using roles, either into a class, or into an object ([mixins of roles](https://docs.raku.org/language/objects#Mixins_of_roles))

Comment: I agree and the documentation even states there are better ways to do the same things. I stumbled over it in [Sort::Naturally](https://github.com/thundergnat/Sort-Naturally) and wanted to play around with it. It is still rather unintuitive `List` has `.show0` depending on the order of the calls.

Comment: but the qualified access via `$list.Any::a-method-added-to-Any` should work, correct?

Comment: Yes, that should.

Comment: Marked as correct answer due to suggesting the use of mixins. Maybe you could provide an example?

Comment: Doesn't [mixins of roles](https://docs.perl6.org/language/objects#Mixins_of_roles) give enough examples?  If so, perhaps we need to improve the documentation.

Comment: Sure it does :) it's just this Stackoverflow thing of link decay that happens from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

A summary of the various comments here and on the issue I created on Github:

As Liz mentioned currently the children types do not see augmentations of their parents. This is true unless there was a flush of the method cache for that type.

This behaviour is a known limitation that will be fixed some time in the future with low priority.

Reconstructing the class with `.^compose` can be used to make augmented methods known to the children:

```
use v6.c;

use MONKEY-TYPING;

augment class Any {
    method show0 { self.say }}

List.^compose;

<hello world>.show0; # OUTPUT: (hello world)
```

Alternatively the qualified class can be accessed directly:

```
use v6.c;

use MONKEY-TYPING;

augment class Any {
    method show0 { self.say }}

<hello world>.Any::show0; # OUTPUT: (hello world)
```